# Ember-cli .config access to env secure?

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-cli

On an ember-cli application, you get access to config., which gives you access to your env file.

If I understand that correctly, you wouldn't want to put anything private in the env file.

For example, I can access config.KEY in the ember app.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

ember-cli which in finality outputs a normal ember app is a client side JavaScript framework.

*ember-cli server is not designed for production,and  if you look forward at how deploy app, ember-cli will generate for you a "classical" ember app under dist when you use `ember build`.*

Thus on a client side framework you don't want to expose "private" nor "secret" nor "sensitive" data as a bit curious client may in finality have access to it.